# Error socket.io al enviar mensajes

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, socket

estoy haciendo una plataforma web usando react, mongodb, nodejs.
Anteriormente tenia problemas de CORS que ya han sido resueltos.

Ahora me muestra correctamente el chat, pero no recibo ni el mensaje de bienvenida ni se envían los que escribo. Si se añade alguien al chat no me avisa... etc, por lo que cualquier interacción que haga con el chat no funciona.

Le adjunto la conexión y creación del chat:

**index.js**

```
const server = http.createServer(app);//creando el server con http y express como handle request
const options={
    cors:true,
    origins:["[url_de_la_web]"],
   }
const client = socketio(server,options);

const {addUser, removeUser, getUser, getUserInRoom} =require('./controllers/user');


server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Server running in"+port)
  })

  

  

client.on('connection', (socket) => {
   
    socket.on('join', ({name, room}, callback)=>{
        const {error, user}= addUser({id:socket.id, name, room});
        
        if(error) return callback (error);
        
        socket.emit('message', {user:'admin', text:`${user.name}, Bienvenido a la sala ${user.room}`});
        socket.broadcast.to(user.room).emit('message',{user:'admin', text:`${user.name}, se acaba de unir!`});

        socket.join(user.room);

        client.to(user.room).emit('roomData', {room: user.room, users: getUserInRoom(user.room)})

        callback();
    });

    socket.on('sendMessage', (message, callback)=>{
      
        const user=getUser(socket.id);
      
        client.to(user.room).emit('message', {user:user.name, text:message});
        client.to(user.room).emit('roomData', {room: user.room, users: getUserInRoom(user.room)});
        callback();
    });


    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
       const user= removeUser(socket.id);

       if(user){
           client.to(user.room).emit('message', {user:'admin', text:`${user.name} ha abandonado la sala.`})
       }
    })
    
});
```

Para llegas hasta este componente se debe de realizar un formulario que te pide el nombre de la sala que quieres crear. Esto me lo realiza bien ya que me muestra el nombre de la sala cuando estoy en el chat.

**Chat.js**

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import queryString from 'query-string';
import InfoBar from './InfoBar';
import Input from './Input';
import Messages from './Messages';


import io from 'socket.io-client';
import './Chat.css';


let socket;

const Chat=({location}) =>{

       const [name, setName] = useState('');
       const [room, setRoom] = useState('');
       const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
       const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
       const ENDPOINT='[url_de_mongodb]'

    useEffect(()=>{
        const {name, room}=queryString.parse(location.search);
        socket=io(ENDPOINT);

        setName(name);
        setRoom(room);
        
       socket.emit('join', {name, room}, ()=>{
        
       }); 

       return () =>{
           socket.emit('disconnect'); //linea 34
           socket.off();
       }
    }, [ENDPOINT, location.search]);


    useEffect(()=>{
        socket.on('message', (message)=>{
            setMessages([...messages, message]);
        });
    },[messages]);

    // funcion para enviar mensajes

    const sendMessage =(event) =>{
    
        event.preventDefault();

        if(message){
            socket.emit('sendMessage', message, ()=> setMessage(''));
        }
    }

    console.log(message, messages);
    
        return (
            <div className="outerContainer">
               <div className="container">
                <InfoBar room={room}/>
                <Messages messages={messages} name={name}/>
                <Input message={message} setMessage={setMessage} sendMessage={sendMessage}/>
               </div>
              

            </div>

        );
   
}

export default Chat;
```

**Messages.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ScrollToBottom from 'react-scroll-to-bottom';
import Message from './Message';
import './Messages.css';

const Messages = ({messages, name})=>(

<ScrollToBottom className="messages">
    {messages.map((message, i) =><div key={i}><Message message={message} name={name} /></div> )}

</ScrollToBottom>
   
    
)


export default Messages;
```

**Message.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ScrollToBottom from 'react-scroll-to-bottom';

import './Message.css';

import ReactEmoji from 'react-emoji';

const Message = ({ message :{user, text}, name }) => {

    let isSentByCurrentUser = false;

    const trimedName = name.trim().toLowerCase();
    if (user === trimedName) {
        isSentByCurrentUser = true;
    }

    return (
        isSentByCurrentUser
            ? (
                <div className="messageContainer justifyEnd" >
                    <p className="sentText pr-10">{trimedName}</p>
                    <div className="messageBox backgroundBlue">
                        <p className="messageText colorWhite">{ReactEmoji.emojify(text)}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            )
            : (
                <div className="messageContainer justifyStart">
               
                <div className="messageBox backgroundLight">
                    <p className="messageText colorDark">{ReactEmoji.emojify(text)}</p>
                </div>
                <p className="sentText pl-10">{user}</p>
            </div>
        )
    )


}

export default Message;
```

Si necesitan más información, solo tienen que pedirmela.
Gracias!!!!

Comment: estás emitiendo una señal llamada _disconnect_, que es un nombre reservado. Usa un nombre que no lo sea.

Comment: lo modifico tanto en index.js como en el chat, ¿verdad? Gracias!

Comment: Gracias ya funciono, el problema ahora es que no se envia ningún mensaje.